# How to estimate the ratio $BF(B^0 \rightarrow \pi^- e^+ \nu_e)/BF(B^0 \rightarrow D^- e^+ \nu_e)$

Tags: quarks, elementary-particles

I would like to estimate the ratio of branching fractions $\frac{BF(B^0 \rightarrow \pi^- e^+ \nu_e)}{BF(B^0 \rightarrow D^- e^+ \nu_e)}$. The difference between the two decays is that in the first decay (top) the $\bar{b}$ quark turns into a $\bar{u}$ quark while in the second one (under) the $\bar{b}$ quark turns into a $\bar{c}$ quark. I thought I could estimate it by multiplying the ratio of the Q-values (to the fifth power) and the relevant CKM matrix elements squared like that:

$\frac{BF(B^0 \rightarrow \pi^- e^+ \nu_e)}{BF(B^0 \rightarrow D^- e^+ \nu_e)} \approx \frac{(m_{B^0}-m_{\pi^-})^5}{(m_{B^0}-m_{D^-})^5} \cdot \frac{|V_{ub}^*|^2}{|V_{cb}^*|^2}$

(the electron mass is neglected)

However this calculation gives a ratio of 0.06, while the PDG values give a result 0.0066. If I take the masses ratio away I get 0.0077 which is closer but then how could I justify ignoring the Q-values?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: ? Brute Q values feels excessive... Look at the [upper (2.1) here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.4389.pdf) to appreciate there is more structure there, in principle....

Comment: Hi @CosmasZachos in my course we only do estimations and do not use (yet) those equations. We usually do the $Q^5$ approximation but I have already seen a few times this product $(m_i \pm m_f)^2 \cdot m_f^3$. However this formula never came in my course so if I cannot derive it logically without QFD then I cannot use it. :)

Comment: @CosmasZachos Ah never mind the $Q^5$ approximation is only valid for $\beta$ decays as far as I can see. Then I guess I was just supposed to compare the CKM matrix elements as approximation. It seems like pure chance to me though that the other factors are almost equal...